# VB.NET Temporarily modify loop's starting value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops

Suppose I have the following code:

```
For intA As Integer = 1 To 5
    For intB As Integer = 1 To 50
        For intC As Integer = 1 to 100
            ...
        Next intC
    Next intB
 Next intA
```

I want to save progress to a db table so that I can continue later on. So, suppose intA is currently 2, intB is currently 14 and intC is currently 54.

Those get saved in a table like so:

```
 intA     intB     intC
========================
  2        14       54
```

Simple enough.

When I want to continue, how can I go about setting each loop to the current, saved value?

I can't simply set the initial loops' starts to the saved values, because that would alter the entire loops' "run".

I could probably use a flag to signal a value has been stored and do something like this:

```
booSavedC As Boolean = IsSavedC  'This resides outside all loops, so "single shot"

For intC As Integer = 1 to 100
    If booSavedC Then
        intC = GetSavedC   'or intC = GetSavedC + 1
        booSavedC = False
    End If

    ...
Next intC
```

However, this renders checking the booSavedC variable every single interation, as well as checking the outer loops' (booSavedB and booSavedA) variables too, etc.

Is there a better, less "expensive" way?

Comment: You would need to use variables for the start value of the loop counters and you can set them to the values from the database.  Inside each loop, simply set the relevant variable to 1, so the loop will start at 1 again on the next iteration of the parent loop.

Comment: well, the values like 1 to 100, the 1 and 100 can be variables instead of hard-coded. So you can set a default value in the DB to start, and use that initially, then next time read from the DB to determine where to continue from before starting the loop. e.g. Dim a as int = 1 For i = a to 100 something like that. I assume you're doing something somewhere which causes you to sometimes exit the loop early - at that point you'd need to save the current value of i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my comment above:

> You would need to use variables for the start value of the loop
>   counters and you can set them to the values from the database. Inside
>   each loop, simply set the relevant variable to 1, so the loop will
>   start at 1 again on the next iteration of the parent loop.

here is an example:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("iMin=1, jMin=1, kMin=1")
        RunLoops(1, 1, 1)

        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("iMin=2, jMin=3, kMin=4")
        RunLoops(2, 3, 4)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub RunLoops(iMin As Integer, jMin As Integer, kMin As Integer)
        For i = iMin To 5
            iMin = 1

            For j = jMin To 5
                jMin = 1

                For k = kMin To 5
                    kMin = 1

                    Console.WriteLine($"i={i}, j={j}, k={k}")
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

You don't necessarily need to reset `iMin` as that loop is only run through once.  It's there for completeness though.

EDIT:

Based on the comment below by @the_lotus and the fact that resetting the start value for the outermost loop is unnecessary, here's some modified code:

```
Sub RunLoops(iMin As Integer, jMin As Integer, kMin As Integer)
    For i = iMin To 5
        For j = jMin To 5
            For k = kMin To 5
                Console.WriteLine($"i={i}, j={j}, k={k}")
            Next

            kMin = 1
        Next

        jMin = 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I just posted a similar answer, I'll delete mine. You can reset the min variable at the end of the loop instead of on each loop. Ex: Reset kMin right after the next instead of inside the loop.

Comment: I got to see your answer @the_lotus and it was spot on. Thanks!

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks @jmcilhinney!